# Google customs maps iframe not working for public

Tags: html, api, google-maps, iframe

I have created a custom Google map, and follow all instructions like share it to everyone (public) and try to embed on my website via iframe.

Here you can see the iframe:[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmhunyxq/)

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=z76-dWS2uqvM.kbKEneg2wOL0" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

It looks ok, when the user is logged-in into the Google account, but if you try to open it in Firefox (logged-out) it returns an empty iframe.

So, when I embed this on my website, people cannot see it. How to make this working, and how to display this multiple pin map to everyone who enters my website?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is an old [issue](http://macosx.com/threads/firefox-cant-see-embedded-google-maps-on-any-page.310917/) which still shows up sometimes. But, try out the steps mentioned in this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/948979). If that doesn't help either, give [this](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3032024?hl=en) a try. And if you're doing this by using the Maps API, [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/maps/embedded$20map$20not$20working$20on$20firefox%7Csort:relevance/maps/quMx7dBz6-Q) might help. Hopefully one of these helps.